# Error :: Add-PnPCustomAction : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

Getting this error:

> Add-PnPCustomAction : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

User has Admin level access on SharePoint Online. PnP PowerShell throws error. Please advice solution here.

Comment: User account has SharePoint administrator or Site collection administrator permissions? Are you able to perform other operations like Set-PnPSite? Can you add the code you are using to your question?

Comment: Would regrant permissions to the user help in your case?